# filter() and map() data to radio buttons in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting data from an API in the following format:

```
const carProperties = [
        {
            "key": "Brand",
            "values": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "Ford"
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "Chevy"
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "Honda",
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "key": "Color",
            "values": [
                {
                    "id": 100,
                    "name": "Blue"
                },
                {
                    "id": 200,
                    "name": "Red"
                },
                {
                    "id": 300,
                    "name": "White",
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

I need to filter this data by its `key` and then map the `values` to HTML elements like radio buttons, check boxes etc. I cannot seem to get the correct syntax to be able to map the values. Here is what I have:

```
carProperties?.filter(property => property.key === "Brand").map((data, index) => (
        <Div key={index}>
            <Form.Check>
                <Form.Check.Input
                    type="radio"
                    id={data.values.id.toString()}
                    value={data.values.name}
            />
                <Form.Check.Label className="form-check-label">{data.values.name}</Form.Check.Label>
            </Form.Check>
        </Div>))
```

The types for `carProperties` are:

```
export interface CarProperty {
    key: string,
    values: CarPropertyValue[]
}

export interface CarPropertyValue {
    id: number,
    name: string,
}
```

Comment: Your syntax looks fine (othr than the capital D in Div, but I guess that's a custom component?). What's not working?

Comment: I'm getting the error: `Property 'id' does not exist on type 'BikePropertyValue[]'.`

Comment: Ah I see, I guess you're not mapping the values.`data.values` is an array, not an object with an `id`.

Comment: You want `filter(property => property.key === "Brand")[0].values.map((data, index) => `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to map the `values` array, not the filtered version of the `carProperties` array. There are a few ways to do this, but if you can guarantee that there's only one object in your `carProperties` that has a `key` of `Brand`, then you should use [`.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) instead of `filter()`. This will stop its search through the array as soon as it finds the brand property, and will return you the object you're looking for which you can then access the `.values` property on, which you can then map:

```js
const brandProperties = useMemo(
  () => carProperties?.find(property => property.key === "Brand"),
  [carProperties]
);
```

The `useMemo()` hook will help avoid researching your array for the `Brand` object each time your component rerenders and instead will only search it once on mount or when `carProperties` changes. Then in your JSX, you can map `brandProperties.values` like so:

```
brandProperties?.values.map(brand =>
  <Div key={brand.id}>
    <Form.Check>
      <Form.Check.Input
        type="radio"
        id={brand.id.toString()}
        value={brand.name}
      />
      <Form.Check.Label className="form-check-label">{brand.name}</Form.Check.Label>
    </Form.Check>
  </Div>
)
```

---

If you can have multiple objects within `carProperties` that have a `Brand` key, then you can use a nested map to map the `values` array of each object to your `Div`:

```js
carProperties?.filter(property => property.key === "Brand").map(carProperty => carProperty.values.map(value => 
  <Div key={value.id}>
    <Form.Check>
      <Form.Check.Input
        type="radio"
        id={value.id.toString()}
        value={value.name}
      />
      <Form.Check.Label className="form-check-label">{value.name}</Form.Check.Label>
    </Form.Check>
  </Div>
))
```

Comment: The nested map example was just what I was looking for. Thanks!